# Ubuntu 10.04 default repository to install MySQL5.5?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, installation

Is there a way to install MySQL 5.5 using apt with the default ubuntu repositories without going third party?

I would like to stick to Apt for update/security patching purposes instead of installing a stand-alone .deb .
But I would also like to use verified repositories for installing any packages.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You are concerned about security. You are running a 2 year old operating system (10.04).  There's a fundamental disconnect here...

Comment: @voretaq7, 10.04 will have coverage by the Security team until 2015-04.

Comment: @Zoredache I think that's optimistic of them based on the versions of some software that shipped with it (and the need to cross major releases to get security fixes) - though I suppose if everything you're using is still actively maintained by heir security folks and they roll patches in that's all that counts :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick with default repositories, you can install only the available package there. Otherwise, you need to find/build your `.deb` file.